# deg of composition on supersingular curve

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let we have supersingular curve $E(\bar{\mathbb{F}_q})$.
Let we have algebraic function $f \in \bar{\mathbb{F}_q}(E)$ with div($f) = \sum_{i=0}^{i=n}n_iP_i$.
Then div$(f)  \circ [q] = \sum_{i=0}^{i=n}n_iQ_i$ where $[q]Q_i = P_i$
($Q_i$ is unique because $E$ is supersingular). So deg$(f)$ = deg$(f)\circ[q]$.
Is it correct reasoning?

Comment: This questions are waaaaay too localized, and even more that you don't even define your stuff: $\,f\,$ is an algebraic function on the elliptic curve? $\,P,Q\,$ are points on the curve?...It'd be better if you could make your questions elf-contained.